# SFML update function not moving sprite

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

The current update function should be moving the sprite to the left 10 pixels every time it's called, but the sprite (cup1Sprite) is static and not moving. I tried using sprite.rotate(); and the sprite rotated every frame (which was expected), so something is wrong with the way I've written the update function for updating the sprite position. Can anyone suggest what's going wrong?

Code:
DrawCups.h

```
class DrawCups
{
public:
    DrawCups(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    ~DrawCups();

    void update();

    void drawCup1();

private:
    sf::RenderWindow& _window;
    //Cup1
    sf::Texture _cup1;        // the texture which will contain our pixel data
    sf::Sprite _cup1Sprite;         // the sprite which will actually draw it
};
```

Update function in DrawCups.cpp

```
void DrawCups::update()
{
    sf::Vector2f pos = this->_cup1Sprite.getPosition();
    pos.x+=10; 
    this->_cup1Sprite.setPosition(pos);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1366, 768), "Sorting Algorithm Visualisation: SFML");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    DrawCups drawToWindow(window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        drawToWindow.update();

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        drawToWindow.drawBench();
        drawToWindow.drawCup1();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm unsure on how to make the question clearer? It's just updating and re-drawing a sprite on an SFML window every frame.

Comment: You may get a better response on the official SFML forums.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted there too. Hopefully will get a response either here or there. :)

Comment: @ConnorWilliams: You make the question clearer by reading and following the instructions on the page I linked.